# Looping through a specific chart in Excel VBA to Change the Series colour

Tags: excel, vba, series

been trying for a while to change the series colour of a specific chart in Excel through VBA. I have the code to change all the charts - this is handy however not all charts have the same number of series. This is what I have so far. For example, if i wanted to change the series colours for Chart 4 only.

```
Sub Serieschange()

    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
         myChart.Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
         myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
         myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 656, 989)
         myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(60, 2, 5)
         myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(20, 900, 3)

         'TRY TO GET CODE TO LOOP FOR SPECIFIC CHARTS
         'If ChartObjects = ChartObjects("Chart 4") Then
         'myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(3, 0, 0)
         'myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(2, 656, 989)
         'myChart.Chart.SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 2, 5)
         'End If
    Next myChart

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd use a helper function returning an array of RGB colours for each series with a select case. Then I'd loop through the series using the array ubound + 1 which will match the number of series.

Comment: Do you want to loop through all `SeriesCollection` objects of every chart to make your code more readable? I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish here. Sometimes a loop is not the best option, especially if you need to modify each entry differently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically I have a Sheet with 6 charts. 4 of them have 5 Series and 2 of them have 3 Series. I'm trying to change the first 4 to be all the same and the last 2 to be all the same. I was thinking to write up this VBA to loop through ALL Charts and change the colour then put an IF statement to change the series of the last 2 charts. Does that make sense? Not sure if I'm explaining myself well here or if my approach is a good one - quite a noob in terms of VBA and programming.

Comment: Your commented out `If` statement is trying to compare `Object`s with an `=`, which will fail.  It should be either `If myChart Is Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 4") Then` (comparing Objects) - or just `If myChart.Name = "Chart 4" Then` (comparing Variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Serieschange()
    Dim series5RGB As Variant
    Dim series3RGB As Variant
    series5RGB = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), _
                      RGB(50, 656, 989), _
                      RGB(60, 2, 5), _
                      RGB(20, 900, 3), _
                      RGB(100, 100, 100))
    series3RGB = Array(RGB(255, 255, 255), _
                      RGB(355, 355, 355), _
                      RGB(555, 555, 555))

    Dim i As Long
    Dim rgbSeries As Variant
    Dim myChart As ChartObject
    For Each myChart In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
        With myChart.Chart
            rgbSeries = IIf(.SeriesCollection.Count = 3, series3RGB, series5RGB)
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
            For i = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count
                .SeriesCollection(i).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = rgbSeries(i - 1)
            Next i
        End With
    Next myChart
End Sub
```

Comment: I thought of this, but OP's code has different sets of RGB depending on the number of series, how do you adjust for that?

Comment: @Damian I hadn't seen the OP's comment to clarify his situation (clearly I should refresh my browser before posting :) ).  I've made an update, just to show a slightly different take.

Comment: Thanks guys. Peter I just tried the code and it worked great).

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, suit as needed:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Serieschange()

    Dim SeriesCounter As Long
    Dim myChart As ChartObject

    For Each myChart In Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects
        With myChart.Chart
            SeriesCounter = .SeriesCollection.Count
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers
            Select Case SeriesCounter
                Case 4
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(50, 656, 989)
                    .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(60, 2, 5)
                    .SeriesCollection(4).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(20, 900, 3)

                Case 3
                    .SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(3, 0, 0)
                    .SeriesCollection(2).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(2, 656, 989)
                    .SeriesCollection(3).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(1, 2, 5)
            End Select
        End With
    Next myChart

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Feels like magic when it does haha. Thanks for the time/effort!

Comment: @apang remember to accept either Peter's or mine answer to close the topic

Answer (score 0):

Run a second loop inside your first loop, to go through each `Series` in the `SeriesCollection` collection.

To make things easier, also define an `Array` to contain as many colours as you think you may need.  (Err on the side of caution - better too many than too few - and consider using `Mod` to "overflow" if needed)

In this example, instead of using `For Each Series In Chart.SeriesCollection`, I have used an integer loop to make getting the Colour from the Array easier

```
Sub Serieschange()
    Dim myChart As ChartObject, MaxColours As Long, CurrentSeries As Long, myColours As Variant
    'Create an Array of the possible colours
    myColours = Array(RGB(255, 0, 0), _
        RGB(50, 656, 989), _
        RGB(60, 2, 5), _
        RGB(20, 900, 3) _
        ) 'Add more colours as desired

    MaxColours = 1 + UBound(myColours) 'If we have more Series than Colours, we can start from the beginning again

    For Each myChart In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects 'Loop through every Chart in the Sheet
        With myChart.Chart
            .ChartType = xlXYScatterSmoothNoMarkers

            If .SeriesCollection.Count > 0 Then 'Check we have any Series to colour first!
                For CurrentSeries = 1 To .SeriesCollection.Count 'Loop through every Series in the Chart
                    .SeriesCollection(CurrentSeries).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = myColours((CurrentSeries - 1) Mod MaxColours)
                Next CurrentSeries
            End If
        End With
    Next myChart

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments and effort dude! On a quick glance I'm guessing this doesn't account for the fact that the colours change depending on the number of series? I tried Peter (and Damians) code above and it accounted for that

Comment: @apang Ah, no, it doesn't.  It is only uses 1 set of colours, but works with any number of series.